# How can I make sure those div's are not overlapping?

Tags: css, html

I have those 2 divs nested into the yellow div, and as you can see the green one is getting under the red one. I would like the green one to sit to the right of the red one. How can I do that? Thanks a lot

The screen shot is at:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cbCI.png

here is my code:

```
.reddiv {
height: 100px;
width: 150px;
background: red;
float:left;
margin:5px;
}

.greendiv {
height: 70px;
width: 300px;
background: green;  
}
```

Comment: That is not enough information, please make a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add float:left to both red and green div and you should be set.

Be warned though that if you need to have another content below yellow div, your content might seem to ignore the height of your yellow div. To tackle that issue, easiest way is to add a third div with clear:both inside the yellow div